# Importing undefined npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, webpack

I have published a npm package.

It works fine when accessing via the global variable `window.Router` in the browser, but when I try to import it using ES module in a Meteor application, it returns `underfined`...

In the lib, I used named export and default export to be sure that the object `Router` is accessible.

However none of the following returns the `Router` object :

```js
// default import
import Router from "jk-router";

// named import
import { Router } from "jk-router";
```

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my Webpack config below, because I have published another npm package that I can import with no problem, the difference is that it's packaged with Gulp.

```
const path = require("path");
const Package = require("./package.json");
const isProd = process.argv.indexOf("-p") !== -1;
const filename = Package.name + (isProd ? ".min" : "");

module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: {
        bundle: path.join(__dirname, "src/router.js")
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: `${filename}.js`
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, "src/js"), "node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of digging, I finally found that I needed to define the `output.libraryTarget` property with the `umd` value in the webpack config. I have found nothing in the official documentation, only a reference on this page : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

The final webpack config looks like this :

```
const path = require("path");
const Package = require("./package.json");
const isProd = process.argv.indexOf("-p") !== -1;
const filename = Package.name + (isProd ? ".min" : "");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: path.join(__dirname, `src/jk-router.js`)
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: `${filename}.js`
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings, this finally fixed my problem after hours of confusion.

Comment: Oh dear god thanks. I've just spent TWO DAYS on this! More details on libraryTarget is here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem, whenever you publish a NPM package, you need to specify the main file at package.json.

https://github.com/jalik/jk-router/blob/master/package.json#L5

I think that the main property points to wrong file, it should be "router.js" and not "jk-router.js".

If you want your filename to remain "jk-router.js" u can change the output field at webpack.config.js file to "jk-router.js"

Comment: The problem is not there because the `dist` folder contains compiled final Javascript, so its the right file that the `main` property is referring. Also I can't point to original source file since it's written in ES6 with modern syntax.. this is why I am using Webpack to transpile to classic JS.

As I said, I have another package with almost the same structure, the only difference is that it uses Gulp instead of Webpack.

Comment: The output file name is filename: `${filename}.js`, so webpack will create a file with jk-router.min.js... please check that the dist folder has the compiled file